# =RANK, but only show top 5 or top 10

Tags: google-sheets

How to use rank feature, but only display the top X results.

List of 30 members, but my ranked list should only contain top results.

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

Let's assume that your original list starts at cell A1 and contains two columns labeled Name and Rank. It is by the values from the second column that five (ten) best results should be selected. First, sort the data in descending order of Rank.

`=SORT(A2:B31,2,FALSE())`

And now we will cut out the first five rows from the resulting array

`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(A2:B31,2,FALSE()),5,2)`

And in order not to lose the table headers, add them to the resulting set

`={A1:B1; ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(A2:B31,2,FALSE()),5,2)}`

The penultimate parameter is responsible for the number of selected rows, in this formula **5**. Change this to 10 and get a different number of rows